# Identify 10 pin smd from Zoom 5g effects pedal

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I may have fried this 10 pin smd by grounding pins 4,5 with the ground lug below it. I can't trace the numbers to anything! From a Zoom G5 effects pedalboard, Any suggestions? 580 9203

[image]

[image]

Comment: The logo appears to be TOREX Semiconductor. and it looks like an MSOP-10 package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Torex [XC9505B092AR](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc9505/XC9505.pdf)

A DC/DC converter as one would expect with those surrounding components, and it fits perfectly with the part marking and package type (MSOP10).
Only discrepancy would be that what looks like an "8" on the part is actually "B".
[image: Marking rule]